# http://localhost:8080/ is not working

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodeJS and triyng to learn it.
I am trying to execute hello world example from http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/node-js-for-beginners/
but i am not getting any output and i am getting No data received page on chrome browser.

I have installed apache (XAMPP) on my PC but it is not active and also when i am trying to run `node http.js` in terminal i am not getting any output.

I have one another file,hello.js which contains `console.log('Hello World!');` 
when i have run `node hello.js` i am getting `Hello World!` output in terminal.
But `http.js` is not working.

http.js code :

```
    // Include http module.
var http = require("http");

// Create the server. Function passed as parameter is called on every request made.
// request variable holds all request parameters
// response variable allows you to do anything with response sent to the client.
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   // Attach listener on end event.
   // This event is called when client sent all data and is waiting for response.
   request.on("end", function () {
      // Write headers to the response.
      // 200 is HTTP status code (this one means success)
      // Second parameter holds header fields in object
      // We are sending plain text, so Content-Type should be text/plain
      response.writeHead(200, {
         'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      });
      // Send data and end response.
      response.end('Hello HTTP!');
   });
// Listen on the 8080 port.
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?  Any hints as to what is going on?  This code works fine for me when i go to localhost:8080 in the browser.  Have you tried typing:  http://127.0.0.1:8080 in your browser?  Both http://127.0.0.1:8080 and http://localhost:8080 works for me in my browser.. but you do need to specify the 8080 port in the url.

Comment: There is no error in console.I have not used proxy here.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I suppose you use node 0.10.x or later? It has some changes in `stream` api, often referred as Streams2. One of the new features in Streams2 is that `end` event is never fired until you consume the stream completely (even if it is empty).

If you actually want to send a request on `end` event, you can consume the stream with Streams 2 APIs:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   request.on('readable', function () {
       request.read(); // throw away the data
   });

   request.on('end', function () {

      response.writeHead(200, {
         'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      });

      response.end('Hello HTTP!');
   });

}).listen(8080);
```

or you can switch stream into old (flowing) mode:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   request.resume(); // or request.on('data', function () {});

   request.on('end', function () {

      response.writeHead(200, {
         'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      });

      response.end('Hello HTTP!');
   });

}).listen(8080);
```

Otherwise, you can send response right away:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

  response.writeHead(200, {
     'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  });

  response.end('Hello HTTP!');
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
//Lets require/import the HTTP module
var http = require('http');

//Lets define a port we want to listen to
const PORT=8080; 

//We need a function which handles requests and send response
function handleRequest(request, response){
    response.end('It Works!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);
}

//Create a server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

//Lets start our server
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

Comment: Wow! Any idea on why this actually worked? The NodeJS example on their website wouldn't load any data for me.