# Nodejs cannot load the page when I connect to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I can run other programs on node.js with no problem. When I want to connect to MySQL through NODE.js it loads forever when I type `nodejs mysqlConnection.js` in terminal and `http://localhost:8080/` in browser.

My Code is as below:

```
// Include http module,
var http = require('http'),
// And mysql module you've just installed.
   mysql = require("mysql");

// Create the connection.
// Data is default to new mysql installation and should be changed according to your configuration.
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   user: "root",
   password: "",
   database: "framework"
});

// Create the http server.
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   // Attach listener on end event.
   request.on('end', function () {
      // Query the database.
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM words;', function (error, rows, fields) {
         response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'x-application/json'
         });
         // Send data as JSON string.
         // Rows variable holds the result of the query.
         response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
      });
   });
// Listen on the 8080 port.
}).listen(8080);
```

**NB: MySQL connection is correct because I connect to my database via PHP with no problem.**

**NB: I have a folder named `node_modules` beside to my js file, inside it I have mysql folder.**

I tried to install nodejs through npm:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>A `request` is ended only when the response has been sent</s>.

<s>You're waiting for the `end` event without ever sending a response (because that response is sent from within the `end` handler, resulting in a sort of deadlock situation).</s>

As @vkurchatkin points out in the comments, if the request stream is being consumed, the `end` handler will be called once it has been consumed entirely, independent of the state of the response. In this case, the request wasn't being consumed at all, meaning that the `end` handler would have been called (as part of the request teardown, probably) only after the response was sent.

So removing the `end` handler altogether should fix the problem:

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  connection.query(..., function(error, rows, fields) {
    // TODO: handle `error`
    response.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'x-application/json'
    });
    response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
  });
});
```

Comment: It opens the download window when I go to the URL. I think header is not recognized.

Comment: Try `application/json`, that's the proper content-type for JSON data.

Comment: "A request is ended only when the response has been sent." - not correct at all

Comment: @vkurchatkin trying to simplify things here. I didn't look at the specifics of when *exactly* a request is ended. Feel free to suggest an alternative and I'll update my answer.

Comment: this topic pops from time to time because of streams1 vs streams2 differences. Here is my answer on one of the questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608330/http-localhost8080-is-not-working/19608663#19608663

Comment: so, the code is correct, but explanation is wrong. The `end` event is emitted, when the stream is consumed, even if it's empty.

Comment: @vkurchatkin fair enough, but in this case it isn't being consumed at all

Comment: @robertklep yeah, either you consume it and do stuff on `end`, or just respond right away if you don't care. But as far as I remember it could cause a memory leak in some cases