# http-server and data from localhost

Tags: javascript, html, networking

I am new to working with Node.js and HTML5 and am having a problem with data on the localhost.  I am trying to read in a data file with an XMLHttpRequest call to a url on the local host. I am using `http-server` and can confirm that the server recognizes the data file by placing this url directly into the browser.  I have an index.html file that loads in the Chrome browser and renders correctly.  The `logic.js` program below successfully loads (based on the console.log(“In main function”) call) but does not use the url in the XMLHttpRequest.

I have looked at serval posts for starting a static page [server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608330/http-localhost8080-is-not-working) and making an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) but I still do not understand what I am doing wrong.

How can I access the data file and display (and then manipulate ) the contents?  What are good resources to better understand the networking process?  Thank you.

```
window.onload = function(){
  console.log("In main function");
  var url = "http://localhost:8080/data/data.json";
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open("GET", url);

  request.onload = function(){
    console.log("in onload");
    if (request.status == 200){
      displayData(request.responseText);
    } else {
      alert("Data Error");
    }
  request.send(null);
  } 
}

var dispLocation = document.getElementById("main");

function displayData(response){
  console.log("Display function");
  dispLocation.innerHTML = response;
}
```

and the index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>JSON Ex</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="logic.js"></script>
</head>
<h1>Main display</h1>
<body>
<div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: 
Based on Mr. Carnate's (or is it The...) I identified the problem as being the way the data file was written.  [This article](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/making_http_requests_js.htm) by [Kirup](https://www.kirupa.com/) was very helpful and may help someone else.

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(request.responseText);` just before calling `displayData()` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, there is an empty line of response in the console that indicates it read the line, but did not return anything.  It did not return "undefined" or "null", just a blank line with the reference on the right hand side of the console.  That should mean that it is reading something for the variable, correct?  Thanks again.

Comment: Added an update...

Comment: It means it is reading an empty space.  I would console.log(request) so you can inspect the object.

Comment: Thanks, you were right, it was a problem with what I was sending in...thanks for your time.